# Trying to get picture to float right of text

Tags: html, css, alignment, floating

I've been working on this all weekend and for some reason I just cannot line this div up properly. I'm trying to get the images to go to the right of the text I have and it won't go, can someone help me see what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: To clarify the small bit of text under the images is supposed to be under the images, I want the images and that small bit of images to float to the right of the huge block of text.

HTML5

```
<section id="content-wrapper"> <!-- Main content of the site -->
    <div id="content">
        <article>
            <header>
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit!!</h1>
            </header><br>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><br>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p><br>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p><br>

            <header>
                <h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p></h2>
            </header><br>

            <ul>
                <li>Lorem </li>
                <li>Lorem </li>
                <li>Lorem </li>
                <li>Lorem </li>
                <li>Lorem </li>
                <li>Lorem </li>
                <li>Lorem </li>
                <li>Lorem </li>
            </ul><br>

            <header>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit!</h2>
            </header><br>

            <header>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h2>
            </header><br>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

            <footer>
                <p>Lorem        &#42;  Lorem        &#42;  Lorem </p>
            </footer>

            <div id="sales-wrapper">
                <div id="sale-item1">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
                        Price: $888
                    </p>
                <div id="sale-item2">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450">
                    <p>
                        ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
                        Price: $888
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="sale-item3">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450">
                    <p>
                        ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
                        Price: $888
                    </p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS3

```
#content-wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 1% auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-color: #F0F8FF;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#content article {
    padding: 3% 5%;
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
}

#content article  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
#content article ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

#content article ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
}

#content article header h2 {
    color: #354175;
}

#content article footer {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

#content article footer p {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 23px;
color: #354175;
}

#sales-wrapper {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: Jsfiddled here : http://jsfiddle.net/kLgyL/, your html is not well-formed.

Comment: Yeah I'm kind of new to web development to be honest. I'm trying to learn how to write cleaner code, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of info on HTML oddly enough.

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems:

1. The image is too large for the page to allow the text to sit on the side.
2. In the main sales-wrapper div you are telling everything to float left and therefore the image doesn't want to sit on the right

For a better solution you could use css to position them properly or use a html table to hold the text on the left and the image on the right. However a simple solution is to decrease the image size and tell the text to float left while the images float right.

That simple solution is represented here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4KNH9/

```
#sales-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    color:white;
}

#floatright {
    float:left;
}
```

If the images you are using are all different sizes you may want to use a table or setting the width and height of the images in css, if you need any help with that let me know.

Comment: Tried this, made my picture smaller and make the width of my p and h statements smaller and the pictures still won't come up to the right.

Comment: The JSFiddle one i made is working fine, try this link: http://jsfiddle.net/4KNH9/2/ and let me know how you go

Comment: That's not what I meant, sorry maybe should have made it more clear. The price is supposed to go below the images. The lage block of text on top is supposed to float to the right of those images and the description area (which is under the image).

Comment: Sorry i dont really understand what layout you want, is it meant to be like this: http://imgur.com/dNZaTQt (the font sizes and stuff screwed up a little there but dont worry about that i did it in microsoft word)

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to do, been working on it all weekend, trying to get it finished today. I still can't see what the problem is.

Comment: Just simply placing it in a table gives you the layout you want quite easily - http://jsfiddle.net/4KNH9/3/ that link should work.